# How to create a graph based on 5 years interval in R

Tags: r, graph, group-by, intervals, summarize

I have two columns, one age and another one is the percentage. I need to draw a graph that shows the distribution of the sum of percentages for each 5 years interval.

`df$group <- cut(df$age, breaks = seq(0,120,by=5), right = TRUE)`

I used the above code to group the age on every 5 intervals and then used group by(age)and summarize(sum=sum(percentage) to sum all percentages on every 5 intervals. However, I'm not able to do that as a "group by" can not work on a categorical variable, Do you know any better way?
if the df is:

```
df <- data.frame(age=c(2,4,6,8), percentage=c(2,3,6,7))
```

and it transformed to below by group by(age) and summarize(sum percentage)
age(0-5, 5-10),   sum percentage(5,13)

but, I need the following:
age(5,10)   ,sum percentage(5,13)

Comment: What do you mean by `However, I'm not able to do that as a "group by" can not work on a categorical variable` ? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your approach but some crucial information is missing. Most importantly, you need to share the data, your syntax, and the errors. The problem might be easy to solve, then.

Comment: I suspect your 'percentage' is actually a character value "5%" is not the same as 0.05. As such, I think you have to convert your percentages to a number, before you can add them together.

Comment: could you please explain more, I'm quite new in R

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new variable with groups and then use `aggregate` to aggregate the percentage values by group and sum them up:

```
df = data.frame(age=c(2,4,6,8), percentage=c(2,3,6,7))
df$age.group = cut(df$age,seq(0,120,5))

sums = aggregate(percentage ~ age.group,FUN=sum,data=df)
```

The result will be:

```
> df
  age percentage age.group
1   2          2     (0,5]
2   4          3     (0,5]
3   6          6    (5,10]
4   8          7    (5,10]

> sums
  age.group percentage
1     (0,5]          5
2    (5,10]         13
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the aggregate code is not working for me

Comment: It should. It's a base function. What do you mean by 'not working'? Maybe, there's something wrong with the syntax.

Comment: after running the aggregate code, nothing is changed in df, I mean percentages are not sum up

Comment: Of course, it is not. The results of `aggregate()` are stored in the new data frame called `sums`. The original dataframe `df` is not affected.

Comment: what a shame! thanks a lot, Just one more question how can I change the intervals from ((0,5],(5,10]) to (5, 10), I mean the highest number in the interval

Comment: You can add labels to the groups. To do that, just add the sequence from 5 to 120 as labels to the `cut()`call: `df$age.group = cut(df$age,seq(0,120,5),labels=seq(5,120,5))`. This will label the first group 5, the next 10, and so on.